# Can I use PHP, MySQL, and Javascript to create an instant messaging system on my website?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, cron, chat

Can I use only these technologies to create a Facebook-like instant messaging/chat feature for my website, or do I need to invoke other technologies, such as cron? I'm running a Linux server.

Comment: Yes you can if you can at all.

Comment: Just search "php mysql chat system" on Google and you'll find answers to your questions...

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq for info on writing appropriate questions

Answer (score 2):

PHP, MySQL and Javascript (using AJAX) will nicely give you the necessary tools for creating a messaging system.

[Some thorough information](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/tutorials/wa-aj-imclient/index.html), keep in mind, though, that this is a long tutorial.

[This should also prove helpful](http://www.pixel2life.com/forums/index.php?/topic/42552-ajaxphp-instant-messaging-system/) and suit your needs accordingly. Not that long of a tutorial either, but very thorough.

I'd recommend taking either of these tutorials with a grain of salt, though. Building your own or using one that's already been build will prove most efficient. Building it for yourself will of course teach you something if this is all new to you as well, so it's a win-win situation if you decide doing it that way.

But consider the fact that there's no shame in using other people's logic. Use the tutorials for a documentation on how others may've done it, and read replies in the threads I posted for you.

Good luck!